# Reverse string message from end to start by 2 chars

Tags: string, vb.net

String:

> 00000C0065060061

Should look like:

> 61000665000C0000

What i tried:

```
   dim data as string
   data = "00000C0065060061"
   ReverseString(data)           ' calling a function

   Function ReverseString(ByVal sText As String) As String
    Dim lenText As Long, lPos As Long
    If Len(sText) = 0 Then Exit Function
    lenText = Len(sText)
    ReverseString = Space(lenText)
    For lPos = lenText To 1 Step -2
        Try
            If lPos > 0 Then Mid(ReverseString, lenText - lPos + 1, 2) = Mid(sText, lPos - 1, 2)
            If lPos = 0 Then Mid(ReverseString, lenText - lPos + 1, 2) = Mid(sText, lPos, 2)
        Catch argEx As ArgumentException
        End Try
    Next lPos
End Function
```

I always have a **System.ArgumentException**, therefore i catch it, and seems it slows down my programm and it becomes laggy. Code above seems correct, any suggestions?

Comment: How you want `00000C0065060061` to be `61000665000C0000` ?
For me, Reversing `00000C0065060061` should be `1600605600C00000`.

Comment: You do not seem to *reverse* the string, you *change* it using some more complicated logic, otherwise, you could just use `Reverse()` / `Join()`. Could you explain this logic?

Comment: Thanks for your atteniton, logic is simple: last two chars becoms first then next 2 chars from end becomes second after first etc, simply saying, im trying to reverse hex from end to the start. Yes, Reverse() reversing chars from end to start, but i need to not reverse chars, i need to change position from end to start by 2 chars, like  i have 6chars data "612000" so after reverse it sould be "002061"

Comment: Where does this data come from?  Why is it a string?  It seems like a sequence of bytes read from some source like a serial port.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway You are right, the data comes from serial in a string format

Comment: You're getting a _string_ from the serial port?  It seems more likely that you'd be getting bytes.  And if so, it is wasted effort to convert them to strings before reversing them.  You can just use `Array.Reverse` directly on the byte array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, Try this:

```
Private Function Reverse(ByVal str As String) As String
    Dim rev As String = ""
    Dim strLen As Integer = Len(str)
    Dim index = strLen - 1
    For i As Integer = 0 To strLen - 1
        Try
            rev = rev + str(index - 1) + str(index)
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
        index -= 2
    Next
    Return rev
End Function
```

**EDIT:**

```
Private Function Reverse(ByVal str As String) As String
    Dim rev As String = ""
    Dim index = Len(str) - 1
    Do While (index > 0)
        rev = rev + str(index - 1) + str(index)
        index -= 2
    Loop
    Return rev
End Function
```

Comment: it doing reverse wrongly. 00000C65060060 became 0600605600C00000. But correct should be 6000065000C0000

Comment: Tried it, it made my prog lag as hell :)

Comment: it works too, but it slows down prog, i think it becouse of exeception

Comment: I think there's no need for this looping. If he input string is big, It will take some time for the loop to finish.

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments, You can try this one line :)

```
Dim Output As String = String.Join("", Regex.Matches("00000C0065060061", ".{2}").Cast(Of Match).Reverse().Select(Function(M As Match) M.Value).ToArray())
```

**Don't forget:**

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
```

To explain the above code:

1. The regex matches each 2 characters and you will have MatchCollection, The first Match in the collection should have first two characters, the second match should have second two characters, etc
2. The MatchCollection will be converted to IEnumerable of Match which will be reversed
3. It will be then converted to IEnumerable of String and then to an array.
4. The array will be joined together to make the output string.

**Note**: This will work only on .NET Framework 3.5 or higher, will NOT work on .NET Framework 3.0 or 2.0

Comment: sorry, never heard about regex before. thanks for additional knowledge.

Comment: Please put `Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions` in your answer. because it puzzled new programmers like me.

Comment: @Youssef13 Both of your answers are working, thanks a lot guys, Youssef13, i think you will not be offended if i accept Killua answer as he was first. THanks both of you again :)